# Firestore auth, use user UID to doc id with ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

i'm trying to use user UID for id of a doc when an user is signup.

in service.ts, I have this line :

```
create_NewStudent(record) {
  return this.firestore.collection('users').add(record);
}
```

And this is my signup function

```
signup() {

     this.afAuth.auth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.pass)
          .then( token => {
      console.log(token.user.uid)


    });


    let record = {};
  record['nom'] = this.nom;
  record['prenom'] = this.prenom;
  record['email'] = this.email;
  record['pass'] = this.pass;
  record['datenaissance'] = this.datenaissance;
  record['lieunaissance'] = this.lieunaissance;
  record['adresse'] = this.adresse;
  record['codepostal'] = this.codepostal;
  record['ville'] = this.ville;
  record['tel'] = this.tel;
  record['secu'] = this.secu;
  record['equipe'] = this.equipe;
  record['poste'] = this.poste;
    this.UsersService.create_NewStudent(uid,record).then(resp => {
  this.nom = "";
  this.prenom = "";
  this.email = "";
  this.pass = "";
  this.datenaissance = "";
  this.lieunaissance = "";
  this.adresse = "";
  this.codepostal = "";
  this.ville = "";
  this.tel = "";
  this.secu = "";
  this.equipe = "";
  this.poste = "";
      console.log(resp);
    })

.then(() => {
               this.modalCtrl.dismiss();
              });
  }
```

For now, when new signup -> it's generate an doc id, but how to use user uid as doc id

[image]

Thanks you for help

Answer (score 1):

using add() will create the new document under a randomly generated id. Assuming you have a way to get your user id. You can put it into firestore using

```
this.firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).set(record);
```

To get the uid at signup

```
 signup() {

     this.afAuth.auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.pass).then( token => {
      console.log(token.user.uid)
 });
```

Comment: But how to get iud because it's when user signup

Comment: Can you mention the method you use for signing up

Comment: signup() {

     this.afAuth.auth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.pass)

Comment: I get the good token in console.log but this.firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).set(record); is in another file (service.ts) so how to set "(iud)" from  "this.UsersService.create_NewStudent(record).then(resp => {" to service.ts Thanks

Comment: So just add another argument in create_NewStudent(iud,record)

Comment: Put the call the create_NewStudent() inside the then callback alongside the steps you take to make the record variable

Comment: Juste done it, but i have this error : uid is not defined

Comment: Just EDIT my post with new version of code but same error

Comment: Using my phone so not in a position to make huge code edits. But what you need to do is put all the record[nom] directly below the then callback (under console.log(token.user.id)